# Userscript to remove Html-Lines, class and Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, userscripts, removeclass

I want to create one short userscript because I hate this annoying yellow smileys!

There are two html lines witch turns the normal smiley ( **:)** ) into the yellow icon

```
 <span class="emoticon_text" aria-hidden="true"> :) </span>

 <span title=":)" class="emoticon emoticon_smile"></span>
```

So, in the first line I have to remove the *class* and the *aria-hidden*

And in the second the whole line, it can be **class="emoticon emoticon_smile"**, but also something like **class="emoticon emoticon_cool"**

I tried with:

`document.getElementsByClassName("emoticon_ text").removeAttribute("aria-hidden");` `document.getElementsByClassName("emoticon_ text").className = "";`

but it failed, so I hope you guys can help me, because my Javescript/jQuery skills are bad..

Thank you

*sorry for my grammar mistakes*

Comment: You have a space on your class name...

Comment: it's only here, not in the userscript, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, which is basically a array of elements matched. You have to iterate trough that collection and run your code for each of the elements matched.

Secondly, you'll need to find the emoticon itself and remove it, for that you need to get each emoticon's parent and tell it to remove the element. In the end, your code will look similar to this:

```
//Finds all emoticon texts
var emoticonTexts = document.getElementsByClassName("emoticon_text");

//Iterate over the results and remove the desired attributes
for (var i = emoticonTexts.length-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    var element = emoticonTexts[i];
    element.removeAttribute("aria-hidden");
    element.className = "";
}

//Find all emoticon images
var emoticons = document.getElementsByClassName("emoticon");

//Iterate over the results and remove them from the page
for (var i = emoticons.length-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    var element = emoticons[i];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

[Also available as an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULz3F/)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using jQuery. Once you have the jQuery library referenced in your project your solution should be as simple as:

```
$(".emoticon_text").removeAttr("aria-hidden").removeClass("emoticon_text");
```